# re-directing webpage to specific page in your directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

How do I do the following:

when the user types in www.mywebsite.com, it goes to www.mywebsite.com/homepage.html

In other words, how do I set up the homepage for a website?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in many ways.

1) One way is to use an HTML redirect. In other words, make your index.html look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/homepage.html">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

2) You could also use a server-side script to redirect. For instance, if your server supports PHP, just make a file named "index.php" with this content and delete index.html/index.htm:

```
<?php header("Location: /homepage.html"); ?>
```

Search engine robots should work fine with this method.

3) If you are using an Apache webserver, you could also use Apache rewrite rules to redirect index.* to homepage.html in say an .htaccess file. This method works only if your Apache web server allows rewrite rules.

4) If you are fine with having the `index.html` page be your true home page, then just rename homepage.html to index.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the 'clean' way (I don't think the `meta`-redirect works with search engines), edit your .htaccess and add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ homepage.html [L]
```

But I suggest you to rename your `homepage.html` to `index.html`. That's way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Rename "homepage.html" to "index.html"

The server will always look for an index file unless told otherwise. So your main page should always have "index" as the file name.